# How to read mp3 in Japanese?

Tags: pronunciation

If I read it word by word in Japanese, it would be 'em pi san'.  But, I once heard someone read it quite differently. How is it read in Japanese?

Comment: Please don’t answer questions in the comment section.

Comment: Although this is rarely talked about, learning to pronounce the Alphabet letters the Japanese way is an important part of Japanese studies.

Answer (score 6):

The correct pronunciation is:

> > エムピースリー

**Refs:**

(1) https://kotobank.jp/word/MP3-1743#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89

(2) https://jisho.org/search/mp3

(3) https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=2222070